# Should i cache microservice API response or not?

Tags: caching, redis

I need to show some events/data inside my product. The data partially resides on my product server and partially on other micro-services. When rendering, i make call to my server which fetches my side data and make an server to server API call to those micro-services. This data is dynamic in nature but changes are not very frequent, so i have planned to cache the response in my side server for quick access. For caching i have planned to use redis. Assume the fetched data size from each micro service does not exceed 5MB(worst case scenario) and the micro service is also my another product.

My question here is, should i cache the API response from each micro service or can make the API call every time a request comes. The data is not constant for every user and varies based on the user accessing it.